# Retrieve a part of an html string from entire html string in iOS

Tags: html, ios, iphone

I want to retrive a part of html string from a full html document eg:

```
"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<title></title>
<meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer">
<style type="text/css">
p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 20.0px '.Helvetica Neue Interface'; color:     #333333; -webkit-text-stroke: #333333}
span.s1 {font-family: '.HelveticaNeueInterface-M3'; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 20.00pt; font-kerning: none}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></span></p>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1">Mauris eget neque eu mi condimentum luctus.<span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></span></p>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1">Maecenas eu nisl luctus, tincidunt orci at, ultrices augue.</span></p>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1"><span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span>Suspendisse sed nulla lacus. Integer<span class="Apple-converted-space">  </span>vulputate sodales.<span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></span></p>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1">Maecenas quis faucibus risus. Sed pellentesque tortor nec leo porttitor sodales. Vivamus imperdiet et diam et pretium. Integer luctus tempus odio eget scelerisque. Curabitur adipiscing sagittis vehicula.</span></p>
</body>
</html>"
```

From this I want to retrive "Mauris eget neque eu mi condimentum luctus.

" with all the enclosing tags.

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIWebview and feed it with your HTML. Then use [-stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString%3a) to retrieve the elements of your HTML, in this case: (note: I have not tested it)

```
NSString *someHTML = [wView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByClassName('s1')[1].innerHTML;"];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using javascript. you need to execute `document.body.textContent` in your webview using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method.

```
NSString *text = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.textContent;"];
```